# opencv error cascadedetect.cpp:1639: error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, opencv3.0, face-recognition

I am following a tutorial for face recognition using python. so this is the code im using

```
    import cv2,os
    import numpy as np
    from PIL import Image

    recognizer = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
    detector= cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

    def getImagesAndLabels(path):
#get the path of all the files in the folder
        imagePaths=[os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)] 
#create empth face list
        faceSamples=[]
#create empty ID list
        Ids=[]
#now looping through all the image paths and loading the Ids and the images
        for imagePath in imagePaths:
    #loading the image and converting it to gray scale
            pilImage=Image.open(imagePath).convert('L')
    #Now we are converting the PIL image into numpy array
            imageNp=np.array(pilImage,'uint8')
    #getting the Id from the image
            Id=int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[1])
    # extract the face from the training image sample
            faces=detector.detectMultiScale(imageNp)
    #If a face is there then append that in the list as well as Id of it
            for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                faceSamples.append(imageNp[y:y+h,x:x+w])
                Ids.append(Id)
        return faceSamples,Ids


    faces,Ids = getImagesAndLabels('trainingImage')
    recognizer.train(faces, np.array(Ids))
    recognizer.save('trainer/trainer.yml')
```

and this is the error message im getting

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/pythonpy/videofacedet/craft/codacus/trainer.py", line 32, in 
    faces,Ids = getImagesAndLabels('trainingImage')
  File "/home/pi/pythonpy/videofacedet/craft/codacus/trainer.py", line 24, in getImagesAndLabels
    faces=detector.detectMultiScale(imageNp)
error: /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1639: error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale

I read somewhere said that the folder I am pointing to (trainingImage) is empty, but it is not. I put my face training images there with the same filename format used by the tutorial author. I wish some one would help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

problem solved. i had my haarcascade xml path wrong. fixed the path,and it is working as expected.